# unity-greeter resolution will not change

Tags: unity, lightdm, display-resolution, i3-wm, unity-greeter

i am using i3 and lightdm, which comes with the default unity-greeter.

i have been battling for days now in trying to change the resolution of the greeter. It is stuck at 800x600px

I have googled and tried all kind of things written on the ubuntu wiki, the manjaro wiki etc.

currently i have the following setup:

a custom configuration file at

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-resolution.conf
```

which contains:

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/screen-resolution
```

the script at `/etc/lightdm/screen-resolution` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 3
xrandr --display Virtual1 --primary --mode 1920x1200
```

when looking in the logs at `/var/logs/lightdm/lightdm.log`

They confirm that the script is being run, with an exit code of 0 (zero) and the sleep also confirms it as a get a 3 sec delay before the greeter screen appears.

I also see the mouse cursor quick at the correct resolution and then it directly switches back to 800x600 so SOMETHING is overriding it.

Anyone that knows anything about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try out that you replace the line

```
xrandr --display Virtual1 --primary --mode 1920x1200
```

with

```
xrandr --output OUTPUT_NAME --primary --mode 1920x1200
```

or, better, with

```
xrandr --output OUTPUT_NAME --primary --preferred
```

in your script, where the possible values for `OUTPUT_NAME` can be obtained via

```
xrandr -q
```

This command will also return detailed information about the connectivity status and the available modes for each output. To list the names of *connected* outputs only, enter

```
xrandr -q | grep -e '\( \)connected' | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }'
```

---

**Some explanation** based on `man xrandr`:

- `--display DISPLAY_NAME` selects the X display to use. Note, however, that this refers to the X screen abstraction, **not** the monitor (or output). [This could be the reason why your script does not work as intended.]
- `--output OUTPUT_NAME` selects an output to reconfigure. Use either the name of the output or the XID.
- `--primary` sets the output as primary.
- `--preferred` selects the preferred mode for the output specified beforehand.

---

**If the above fix does not work**, it is worth trying the alternative

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/screen-resolution
```

hook in your configuration file. Also, in some cases, it might be necessary to explicitly transfer the ownership of the script file to LightDM. This can be done via

```
sudo chown lightdm:lightdm /etc/lightdm/screen-resolution
```

(In your case this last step is probably irrelevant, since according to your observation LightDM can already execute the script.)

---

If you are using a **multi-monitor setup** (or a laptop with a docking station), you are probably better off with a slightly more elaborate script that can recognize whether the intended primary display is connected and act accordingly. See, e.g., [here](https://gist.github.com/RyanMillerC/c48d9f63f8fe386b22a7da18cf6913d2).